# Expression "let's cross that bridge a little further down the road"

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions

I've heard the expression "let's cross that bridge a little further down the road" to convey something I understand a bit like: "let's take that difficult decision a bit later" or "let's take on that challenge a bit later". Can the expression be interpreted like that? Any other ideas?

Comment: Not *directly* related, but "People in glass houses sink ships"

Comment: It’s a mixed metaphor. In my not-so-humble opinion, you should avoid using expressions like this as much as possible, because they create confusing mental images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Let's not worry about that until further down the road*," and "*Let's cross that bridge when we get to it*" are two ways to idiomatically express "*Let's defer that until later, and stay focused on the topic at hand right now*."

The phrasing you gave sounds like a combination of those two idiomatic expressions - be it inadvertent or deliberate (much like when someone says "*ginormous*")

Answer (score 6):

You are correct, but it's an uncommon mixture of common metaphors: "crossing the bridge" and "down the road". A more popular expression for a similar concept is *we'll cross that bridge when we come to it*, often used when trying to remove undue worry about an upcoming event.

Comment: Perhaps the road has a selection of bridges from which to choose.

Comment: "_We'll cross some bridge, after we get to the fork in the road_" - is that what you're saying? :^)

Comment: I imagined OP taking a riverfront ramble and having both civil and natural choices for traversing said river.  :)

Answer (score 6):

*Let's cross that bridge when we come to it.* Let's not make that decision prematurely.

*Kick the can down the road.* Let's put off doing whatever it is that we're talking about.

So you've got a mixed metaphor here. I'd take it to mean avoiding the need to make a decision.

Comment: +1: "mixed metaphor" is the name for this kind of thing.